# Binary Tree search an unsorted matrix?

Tags: python, sorting, matrix

is there a way to Binary Tree search an unsorted matrix? If yes, could you explain it as I am new to programming? I have tried implementing it using nested `for i for j` for loops but was wondering if there is a faster way.

```
import numpy as np

matrix = [[3, 6, 7], [9, 1, 2], [8, 4, 5]] 
matrix = np.array(matrix)  
matrix
array([[3, 6, 7],
       [9, 1, 2],
       [8, 4, 5]]) # how does one perform a binary tree search on an unsorted matrix?
```

Comment: The nature of binary search is that it requires the the structure being search to be sorted. It doesn't work otherwise.

Comment: What are you trying to search?

Comment: @MarkMeyer could you potentially perform a Binary Sort then Binary Search?

Comment: @PyWalker2797 I am trying to search for all occurrences of 8 in a large unsorted matrix in the fastest possible time

Comment: There is no such thing as "binary sort".

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.where` for this.

```py
matrix = np.array([[3,6,7],[9,1,2],[8, 8, 8]])
dim_1, dim_2 = np.where(matrix == 8)
#dim_1 = array([2, 2, 2], dtype=int64)
#dim_2 = array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int64)
#dim_1, dim_2, dim_3 = np.where(matrix == 8) if matrix had shape (3, )
num_8 = len(ret[0]) #total number of 8's
```

`np.where` returns a tuple of arrays separated by indexes based on the shape of your array. If you have a 3D array you will get 3 arrays in your tuple.
`ret = (array([2, 2, 2], dtype=int64), array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int64))`
`ret[0]` corresponds to the row values, and `ret[1]` corresponds to the column values.
So this means that the element 8 is present in `matrix[2][0]`, `matrix[2][1]`, `matrix[2][2]`

Does that help? You won't have to write your own routine for this. Pretty sure this will be faster than any search routine you will implement in pure python because NumPy built-in functions are highly optimized. You should consider using NumPy methods for NumPy arrays wherever possible.

Comment: Hi @PyWalker2797 thank you for your answer. Does ```np.where``` uses Binary Tree under the hood? Tried looking at the code, seems like they use a dictionary.

Comment: I don't think so, binary search requires the data to be sorted. Hashmaps / Dictionaries are good for data retrieval on unsorted data. Which makes them faster in this case.